# Energy inside charged conducting sphere

Tags: potential-energy

We know that energy of a solid(or hollow) conducting sphere sphere is KQ^2/2r this energy is distributed from
r  to infinite  and we say that energy inside is zero... Now  we know that electric field is also zero  in side   hence potential is constant inside but we also know that potential is related to potential energy ( energy per unit charge) and if potential is constant inside then energy should also be uniform distributed inside... But it is not in actual..,.... Why?????

Answer (score 0):

The electric potential tells you how much potential energy a small test charge would have *if it were present*. Since there is no charge inside the sphere, there is no potential energy inside due to the potential inside.

Comment: Thanks....  I  have seen